# Assigning a delegate to a CALayer's sublayer throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates, drawing, calayer

I'm trying to use a series of CALayers as sublayers to a view that needs a little more fine grained drawing than usual. I've been using `CATiledLayer` before, and I thought using sublayers would be easier, if not equally finicky. I figured I perform a `[self.layer addSublayer:sublayer]`, set the delegate of that new sublayer and then I draw all I want in the `drawLayer:inContext:` method. But to my great surprise, ***my app crashes on `addSubview:`*** (without IB) or somewhere higher up the call stack (when using IB).

#### According to the docs ...

The [CALayer reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW126) seems to dictate exactly what I'm doing, yet it crashes every time:

> *In iOS, if the layer is associated with a UIView object, this property must be set to the view that owns the layer.*

But obviously, I'm screwing something up. Thankfully, it's easily reproducible. Can you explain to me how I should be using sublayers with delegate assignments to receive the right `drawLayer:inContext:` calls without crashing?

#### Steps to reproduce

Put this in the class of a custom view put on screen with Interface Builder (or rewrite the init to be called `initWithFrame:`):

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        CALayer *sublayer = [CALayer layer];
        sublayer.frame = self.layer.bounds;

        // Disable or enable this next line to 
        // resolve or trigger an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash.
        // 
        sublayer.delegate = self;

        [self.layer addSublayer:sublayer];
        [self.layer setNeedsDisplay];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx {
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, self.bounds);
}
```

If you run this code, your app will crash. Mind the `sublayer.delegate = self` line. If you disable that one, your app will run, but the `drawLayer:inContext:` method is never called for that sublayer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This does not work because the UIView you are subclassing (I assume it is a UIView) already is the delegate of its own CALayer, it cannot be the delegate of more than one CALayer at once. This post has some more details:

[Using CALayer Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2015353/using-calayer-delegate)

Comment: Thanks for the post, I couldn't find that one, neither does it show up in the "related" column. Any clue as to why Apple disallows the double delegate assignment? Thanks!